# MMVM Listbox gets data via MQTT but does not display it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have this problem for some time already. I want to receive some data via MQTT and display these messages in a ListBox. It has worked without MVVM, but not with it.

What happens is that the data gets revieved and passed to the ListBox. When I hove over the ListBox, I can see that there is some data since it shows an item can be displayed.

My code is the following:

View

```
public partial class ShellView : Window
{
    public ShellView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ShellViewModel();   
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
ObservableCollection<string> _data = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> Data
{
    get
    {
        return _data;
    }
    set {
        _data = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
    }
}
#region INotifyPrortyChanged

public const string propertyName = "Data";
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Part of the ViewModel where I suspect the error

```
private void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        _data.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));
    });

    foreach (string o in _data.ToList())
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(o); shows that the string "json" is recieved
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(o); same here
            Data.Add(o);
        });
    }
}
```

View.Xaml

```
ListBox x:Name="lBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Background="White" Grid.Column="1" Margin="192,52,134,10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Background="red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If someone could help me figuring out the problem in my code, it would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `{Binding Path=Value}` doesn't make sense, because each item is a primitive `string` and doesn't have Value property. try make it `{Binding Path=.}`

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much.
Your explanation also makes sense. If you put it as an answer, I will gladly check it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItemsSource has type `ObservableCollection<string>`, so each element in ListBox is a primitive `string`.

But inside ItemTemplate you have this binding: `{Binding Path=Value}`. `string` doesn't have `Value` property, so text value cannot be resolved and nothing is displayed.

Change the binding to `{Binding Path=.}` or simply: `{Binding}`

Debugging tip: look into Visual Studio `Output` window - IDE reports incorrect bidnings there with details (like not existing property names, type mismatches and so on)